# How does ethernodes.org discover nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, light-clients, ethernodes

I am running my light-client at the moment and wanted to know, how does ethernodes.org discover nodes?

And is it possible to get discovered using a light node?

Thanks in advance!